# Prism Multiple Window/Overlays Display

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have created a prism application that do's a variaity of things trough modules.
Now i have created a module where there are 3 overlay that needs to be displayed (3 Views).
What i want todo is when i click a button in the shell view, the 3 overlays  would need to be displayed without locking up with the main window(shell view)

Note: the 3 Overlay's need to be always on top.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction on how to do this with prism/mvvm or a other way :)

Regards
And Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: ... and `Window.Show` fails exactly _why_?

Comment: I can't really do that since prism handles everything. (module loading and so on)

Comment: click button, execute command, create window, show window... prism doesn't handle everything, it doesn't even create your main window :-)

Comment: This seems to be standard Prism stuff.  If I understand you correctly, the 3 areas with overlays should be named prism regions.   When you click the button, you would use the RegionManager to navigate those regions to the overlays you want.  Something like that

Comment: There is one prism module (module b) that need to start 3 differant windows(away from the mainshell).
The main shell only needs to be aware that the overlay's exists so it can push data to it.

Just back from work, will look tonight at all the replyes (hope i explain everything good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simpel.
What it comes down to is implementing a custom service dialog system.